# Selling my legal game. What to do about the activation part?

Tags: flight-simulator-x

I've sold my Microsoft Flight Simulator X game. Its a legal game. I have the cd keys, and I've activated it and can peacefully play it.

Now that I've sold it (it still hasn't reached him yet), what do I have to do regarding the activation? How do I deactivate? Do I simply uninstall the game when I am online? Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FSX EULA makes no mention of it being none-transferable. I've "activated" the game myself on numerous computers, and it's never come back saying "You need to de activate on another device". Just uninstall the game, as you would when transfering it to another device; and that should be all that is required.

It does connect with MS when activating the key, but it doesn't do any such thing when uninstalling (just checked). So... there shouldn't be any issues. Your buyer should be able to install it just fine with the key.